# Make a list of values line up with a textarea and labels

Tags: html, css, layout, textarea

Here's some CSS and HTML to make a textarea below a list of data points:

```
form label {
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
}
form ol li {
  background: #98c8dc;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

<form>
<ol>
<li>
  <label><br/><br/><br/><br/>Recent data</label>
  <ol>
  <li>3 99</li>
  <li>5 98</li>
  <li>15 97</li>
  <li>28 96</li>
  </ol>
</li>
<li>
  <label>New data</label>
  <textarea placeholder="30 95" rows="4"></textarea>
</li>
</ol>
</form>
```

It renders like this:

[image]

How would you recommend I get it to line up just right?
Namely, "Recent data" should line up with the "28 96" line and, perhaps trickiest, the "30 95", despite being in the textarea, should line up as if it's just another row that comes after the "28 96".

Comment: Can anyone advise me on bounty etiquette? I wanted to give it to @Bee for jumping in and nailing it within 24 hours of my asking. No one has improved on her answer in terms of the quality of what's rendered, but it's been topped in terms of the elegance of the code. Can I, for example, make the most elegant solution the accepted one but award the bounty based on speed of answer? I mean, I know I can, but what's most in the stackoverflow spirit? (Disclosure: Bee and I are co-hackers in real life.)

Comment: As I understand bounty can be split and is not bound to the accepted answer

Comment: In your HTML code, you shouldn't use a label for recent data as there's no corresponding form element. A span or inlined p with exactly the same style as the label below would be OK (my preferred naming is a class .label_like ^^). And you should add a for/id association between label and textarea as usual for form elements associated with a label.

Comment: This may be splitting hairs, but semantically, if you're going to apply `list-style: none;` to list items, you should consider using `ul` rather than `ol` since there is no alphabetical or numerical _ordering_ - they're just bullet points without the bullets. ;-)

Comment: (It didn't let me split the bounty. I made Ricardo Tomasi's answer the accepted one. It deserves more upvotes, too! Thanks so much for all these great answers, everyone!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good case for CSS positioning. Elements with `position:absolute` are positioned relative to their closest *positioned* parent. That means we can anchor the labels to the top/left of their containers using `position:relative` on the `<ol>`, and `position:absolute` on the label.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/YhQYS/1/

**HTML**:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    <ol>
        <li class="recent-data">
          <strong>Recent data</strong>
          <ol>
              <li>3 99</li>
              <li>5 98</li>
              <li>15 97</li>
              <li>28 96</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="new-data">
          <label>New data</label>
          <textarea placeholder="30 95" rows="4"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ol>
</form>
```

**CSS**:

```
form > ol {
    background: #98c8dc;
    font-family: serif;
}
.recent-data > ol,
.new-data > ol {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    line-height:20px;
}
.recent-data li { padding-left:5px; }
.recent-data,
.new-data {
    position:relative;
    padding-left:140px;
}
.recent-data strong,
.new-data label {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    line-height:20px;
}
.recent-data strong { bottom:5px; }
.new-data label { top:5px; }
.new-data textarea {
    font-family:serif;
    font-size:100%;
    padding:4px;
}
```

This is very simple to reason about, and reliable cross-browser. Note that you shouldn't use a `<label>` that doesn't have a correspondent form control.

---

**But** that stuff looks like tabular data... it's your choice, we don't have enough context to know what mark-up is more appropriate. So here is a more semantically correct approach using tables, `rowspan` and `vertical-align`:

**HTML**:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    <table id="results">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="4" scope="row" class="recent-label">Recent data</th>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>47</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>99</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>98</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>98</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="1" scope="row" class="new-label">New data</th>
                <td colspan="2" class="new-data">
                    <textarea>23</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**CSS**:

```
form {
    background: #98c8dc;
    font-family: serif;
}
#results th,
#results td {
    padding:3px 5px;
}

#results .recent-label {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
#results .new-label {
    vertical-align:top;
}
#results .new-data {
    padding-left:0px;
}
#results textarea {
    padding:4px; // +1px border
    font-size:100%;
    font-family:serif;
}
```

Sample at http://jsfiddle.net/quqf8/1/

Answer (score 5):

Vertical-align doesn't work in inline elements but does work in tables ([more details on vertical-align](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)).

So here's a solution: I just wrapped the two main elements in the first `li` in a table row, and set the vertical align to bottom to force the 'recent data' label to the bottom. (There might be some way using the `display` property to change the `li` from an inline element?)

You'll also need to tweak the padding on the `ol` and the `label`s and `table` tags so that everything lines up. In real life you probably use some sort of reset css to normalize the default style rules for all these different elements, so you might have to make different tweaks to get everything to line up perfect, but here's what I came up with.

[image: Altogether now]

Altogether now:

```
<style>
table,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   outline:0;
   font-size:100%;
   vertical-align:baseline;
   background:transparent}
body{line-height:1}
ol,ul{list-style:none}
table {border-spacing: 0px;}
table td{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

* {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Times New Roman, serif;
} 
form label {
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
} 
form ol li {
  background: #98c8dc;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
} 
form ol li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
form li label{
  padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
} 
</style>

<form>
<ol>
<li>
<table><tr><td>
  <label>Recent data</label>
</td><td>
  <ol>
  <li>3 99</li>
  <li>5 98</li>
  <li>15 97</li>
  <li>28 96</li>
  </ol>
</td>
</tr></table>
</li>
<li>
  <label>New data</label>
  <textarea placeholder="30 95" rows="4"></textarea>
</li>
</ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want stuff to behave like a table, display it like a table. Use CSS's `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` for the `display` property of the elements. You can then use vertical align and other table 'only' stuff. Note that I used `>` for the CSS selectors so the internal lists don't get those styles too.

http://jsfiddle.net/nQWBw/2/

CSS:

```
.table-like {
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #98c8dc;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.table-like > LI {
    display: table-row;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.table-like > LI > LABEL ,
.table-like > LI > OL ,
.table-like > LI > TEXTAREA {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed magenta;
    /* padding: 5px 10px; */
    vertical-align: top;
}
.table-like LI:first-child > *{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.table-like > LI > OL > LI {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <ol class="table-like">
        <li>
            <label>Recent data</label>
            <ol>
                <li>3 99</li>
                <li>5 98</li>
                <li>15 97</li>
                <li>28 96</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>New data</label>
          <textarea placeholder="30 95" rows="4"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the border and padding from the `textarea` and set it to the same font.

Roughly, http://jsfiddle.net/vP7As/1/

Comment: Ah, thanks for the jsfiddle link! But I don't think that works. It looks terrible to have no border on the textarea, don't you think?

Comment: true, you could always set the border to 1px then add a margin to the other items with 1px.

Answer (score 2):

here is a solution. `no table`, `no jquery`, just add one `p` tag in first `lable`

[Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRbV2/)

Tested in safari 15, firefox 6, and ie8.

I think you should set a `line-weigh` for caculate. In example, I set `18px` so that the whole height in `<ol><li>3 99...</ol>` is `(18+5+5)*4=112px`(two 5px for your li:padding height), then add one `p` tag easy for a `position` control.

HTML part:

```
<form>
<ol>
<li>
    <label><p>Recent data</p></label>
  <ol>
  <li>3 99</li>
  <li>5 98</li>
  <li>15 97</li>
  <li>28 96</li>
  </ol>
</li>
<li>
  <label>New data</label>
  <textarea placeholder="30 95" rows="4"></textarea>
</li>
</ol>
</form>
```

CSS part:

```
form{font:14px/18px arial;}

form label {
  width: 140px;
  float: left;  
}
form>ol>li>label {
     height: 112px; 
     position:relative;
}
form>ol>li>label>p {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;  /* 5px for the last li(28.96) padding-bottom:5px   */
    left:0;
}
form ol li {
  background: #98c8dc;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Using some `position: reltive;` you can make it all line up.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
form {
background: #98c8dc;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
form label {
width: 140px;
float: left;
position: relative;
bottom: 20px;
display: block;
}
form label span {
display: block;
}
form ol li {
display: table-row;
list-style: none;
}
#area {
position: relative;
right: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<ol>
<li>3 99</li>
<li>5 98</li>
<li>15 97</li>
<li>28 96</li>
</ol>
<label><span>Recent data</span>New data</label>
<textarea id="area" placeholder="30 95" rows="4"></textarea>
</li>
</ol>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However it does look like you are working with tabular data, in which case simply using a table would probably be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical align works with `inline-block` elements
http://jsfiddle.net/s3ayp/

---

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form>
  <ol>
    <li class="lineup lineup-bottom">
      <label >Recent data</label>
      <ol>
        <li class="first">3 99</li>
        <li>5 98</li>
        <li>15 97</li>
        <li class="last">28 96</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="lineup lineup-top">
      <label>New data</label>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <textarea placeholder="30 95" rows="4"></textarea>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

---

```
 /* CSS */
.lineup > * {
    display: -moz-inline-box; /* FF 2 */
    display: inline-block;
}
*:first-child + html .lineup > * { /* IE7 hack */
    display: inline;
}

.lineup.lineup-top > * {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.lineup.lineup-bottom > * {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
form label {
    width: 140px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
ol {
    background: #98c8dc;
    list-style: none;
}
ol li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
ol li.first {
    padding-top: 0
}
ol li.last {
    padding-bottom: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Some JQuery

You can set label padding dynamically with jquery using list element number.

http://jsfiddle.net/uSehQ/2/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var size = $("#data").children().size();
    var top = 5+30*(size-1);
    $("#label").css("padding", top+"px 0 0 0")
});
</script>
<style>
form label {
  width: 140px;
  float: left;
}
form ol li {
  background: #98c8dc;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
</style>
<form>
<ol>
<li>
  <label id="label">Recent data</label>
  <ol id="data">
  <li>3 99</li>
  <li>5 98</li>
  <li>15 97</li>
  <li>20 25</li>
  <li>30 95</li>
  </ol>
</li>
<li>
  <label>New data</label>
  <textarea placeholder="40 76" rows="4"></textarea>
</li>
</ol>
</form>
```